# contenteditable loose focus but writes anyway

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, contenteditable

I am using `Foundation` `alert-box` and `joyride`. I am experiencing a strange issue;
when I write in `contenteditable` and open an `alert-box`, when I close the `alert-box` (with the `x`) and then I type again (random char) even if the `contenteditable` has loose its `focus` ( I checked with `document.activeElement` ) the typed letter is inserted in the `contenteditable`, the `keypress` **not** fired on the `contenteditable` and a `keydown` `event` is fired on the `body`.

This happens in `Chrome`, in Firefox works as well.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sohzjv5/1/)

To get the problem: while you have focus on `contenteditable`, then click on the `alert-box` "x" (`contenteditable` will loose focus), it will type anyway in the `contenteditable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with:

```
$("#mycontenteditable").on("blur", function(){
   var sel = document.getSelection();
   sel.removeAllRanges();
})
```